# Is it possible to use Views for listing data created in a custom module?

Tags: 7, views

The title says it all.

I'd like to create a view and provide rows for that view from a custom module where I've prepared the data for it.

The data is prepared when a page is visited and a callback function has run, the data is not stored in the database.

Is that possible somehow?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure someone can give you a proper detailed answer but until then check out hook_views_data() - https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7

Comment: I don't mean to pull data from a database table, the data is prepared when a page is visited and a callback function has run. I don't think this question is a duplicate because the other answer works from db table.

Comment: Oh in that case, if the data isn't actually stored anywhere views cannot use it.

Comment: @BálintDeáki The data must be _somehwere_, otherwise it doesn't exist. You say you prepare it in a page callback - where does the data that you use to prepare that come from in the first place? That's the datasource you need to expose to views

Comment: @Clive when the page is visited, the callback function retrieves data from an API, stores it in arrays. Is that possible to use that data in a view?

Comment: Anything's possible :) [Views datasource](https://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) exists for exactly that, but it's in dev so your mileage may vary

Comment: @Clive For me it doesn't seem like that module would help. It seems like that's a module for providing data already listed by Views in certain formats. I need to give my data to Views so it can list it and do all sorts of viewsy things with it.

Comment: @Clive mainly use auto refresh module on it, so whenever you data comes in from the API, it would refresh without page reload

Comment: @BálintDeáki My mistake, I don't think there is a module for that then. It's theoretically possible (anything is), but the amount of work you'll have to do to convert Views from using DB to external API might make you think twice about it (you'll need to write pagers, filter handlers, aggregators, relationship handlers, the works). The quickest solution would be to cache your API data in a local DB table so views can get easy access to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know link-only answers are generally frowned upon, but this series of blog posts are unlikely to ever go anywhere and are WELL worth a read:

[Building Views Query Plugins: Part 1](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/building-views-query-plugins) - *Mapping web service data to the Views model*

[Building Views Query Plugins: Part 2](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/building-views-query-plugins-part-2) - *Writing and testing the plugin itself*

[Building Views Query Plugins: Part 3](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/building-views-query-plugins-part-3) - *Exposing options and configuration*

[Building Views Query Plugins: Part 4](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/views-query-plugins-part-4) - *Building custom pager plugins*

*Note: In the unlikely event that someone gets here and the links are dead, please comment and let me know so I can address it :-)*

Comment: Whoa! That's probably what I need, it'll be quite the challenge to get through this. Thank you!